# Accessing HttpServletRequest and Response from JSR223 sampler within Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter, jsr223

I am using a custom SDK with the following method:

`public Optional<User> retrieveUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)`

in the jmeter, I am using JSR223 sampler to access this method:

```
all the imports here
.
Optional<User> userProfile = new SdkClass().retrieveUser(request,response);
```

where request and response are HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse

In the step before JSR223, I have an HTTPRequest Sampler where the user logs in and a cookie gets created. My question is that how do I pass the request and response to

`new SdkClass().retrieveUser(request,response);` ?

The request should have the cookie that was created in the previous step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to get previous request and response details

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampleResult;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy;

HTTPSamplerProxy previousSampler = ctx.getPreviousSampler();
CookieManager cookieManager = previousSampler.getCookieManager();
HTTPSampleResult previousResult = (HTTPSampleResult)ctx.getPreviousResult();
```

See JavaDoc on the aforementioned classes:

- [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html)
- [CookieManager](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/control/CookieManager.html)
- [HTTPSampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampleResult.html)
- `ctx` is a shorthand to [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html)

Make sure you add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to your Test Plan elsewise you'll get `null` on attempt to access it via `getCookieManager()` method.